# Is there a way to be more performatic in my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to improve my function because it is being Terminated due to timeout when the arr or the queries is too big. It is a simple function to do some operations in a array pre-defined with a length n, and the queries defines the operations to do into array (arr).

Each line of a query means the range (queries[i][0] is the beginning and queries[i][1] is the final range from arr[]). And the value to sum the arr (queries[i][2]). So, if the queries have three rows, we have three operations to do. This function returns the max element from this arr.

Is there something to improve this code?

I think that `Array(n).fill(0)` and `Math.max.apply(Math, arr)` can be the problem.

Otherwise, in while loop, is there some way to do the verification and operation once rather than walking through the array and doing verification at each element? Thanks

```
 function arrayManipulation(n, queries) {
    var a;
    var b;
    var k;
    var i = 0;
    var arr = Array(n).fill(0);
    while (queries[i] != undefined) {
        a = (queries[i][0] - 1);
        b = (queries[i][1] - 1);
        k = queries[i][2];
        for (a; a <= b; a++) {
            arr[a] = (arr[a] + k)
        }i++
    }
    k = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
    return k
}
```

Comment: When are you stopping the while loop? The error begins on it, because there aren't conditions that queries[i] is undefined in the loop.

Comment: do you have a small example and the wanted result?

Comment: You may want to consider [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Not that code review questions aren't on-topic here, you just may have better luck there.

Comment: @LucasCosta should stop when overshoot the array length

Comment: Yeah, now I saw, thanks @charlietfl.

Comment: It's more idiomatic to use either `queries.forEach()` or `for (i = 0; i < queries.length; i++)`.

Comment: It's a **query** - not a "querry" - one "r" is **quite** enough!

Answer (score 0):

Every iteration of the loop, you repeat the same lookup into the array, `queries[i]`, four times:

```
    while (queries[i] != undefined) {
        a = (queries[i][0] - 1);
        b = (queries[i][1] - 1);
        k = queries[i][2];
//...
```

Do the same with a `for` loop:

```
var query;
for (var i = 0, len = queries.length; i < len; i++) {
   query = queries[i];
   a = query[0] - 1;
   b = query[1] - 1;
   k = query[2];
// ...the rest of the loop
}
```